# How to round sale price to the first decimal digit?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce 3.5.3 and Woocommerce All Discounts plugin from Orion.
After I am applying the discounts. The prices look like this: €59.90 -> €47.92, 
€69.90 -> €55.92. etc.

How can I round it to the first decimal digit?

I have already tried a few solutions but none work. For example:

```
function round_price_product( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    return round( $price );
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php? Third parameter should update it (`PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP`). Is the `€` in the variable?

Comment: what does decimal mean? are you trying to round up to the nearest euro or cent?

Comment: I'm trying to trying to get values rounded to the 1st decimal point. For ex. 47.90 instead of 47.92.

Comment: `47.90 instead of 47.92` is not what the question says, that also is rounding down, not up, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah sorry for my english.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want `59.90` to be rounded to `47.92`? How is that possible?

Comment: This is an example after applying the discount. Original price is 59.90 and applying 20% discount the Sale price is 47.92. I'm trying to have the sale price rounded to 47.90

Answer (score 1):

If we split the price in integers and fractions then we can round the fractions and use str_pad to make sure we don't loose a digit (47.9 instead of 47.90)

Because we divide the fraction with 10 we get a new fraction that can be rounded with zero precision.
Then multiply it with 10 to get it "back" as originally.

```
function round_price_product( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    $parts = explode(".", $price);
    $parts[1] = round($parts[1]/10,0)*10;
    if($parts[1] == 100) { // round up to next integer
        $parts[0]++;
        $parts[1] = 0;
    }
    return $parts[0] . "." . str_pad($parts[1], 2, 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
}

echo round_price_product("47.92"); //47.90
// 47.95 -> 48.00
// 47.02 -> 47.00
```

https://3v4l.org/92sO1

Comment: And I should just add this to functions.php on my theme? Tried it and it has no effect.

Comment: I don't know where you need to put it. You need to figure that out yourself. But it should do something. If nothing else, create an error. Got errors off?

Comment: @Elcorso the code does work as you can see in the link. It must be on your end something is not right